# Why does a message send cause a retain cycle warning in ARC, but a property set does not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

```
[self.foo setBlock:^{
    [self doSomething]; // causes warning
}];
```

versus

```
[self.foo setBlock:^{
    self.bar = baz;     // does not cause warning
}];
```

The warning being "Capturing `self` strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle."

Don't both lead to a strong reference?

Comment: if the change the second example to `[self setBar:baz];`, do you get the warning?

Comment: Yes, if I set the property via that syntax then I do.

Comment: Compiler bug.  Likely fixed in a later version.

Comment: I see. This is xcode 4.5 FWIW.

Comment: Pretty weird. `self.bar = baz` and `[self setBar:baz]` is supposed to be the same :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler bug and you should file a bug report with Apple.

Both are the same, `a.b = c` is just a different way for writing `[a setB: c]`. If the compiler handles one differently from the other this is a bug.